# Why doesn't CC.net devenv task fail when a project is missing from the solution?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I've just realised that one of my Cruise Control.net code integration builds has been succeeding despite the fact that a project's missing from the solution (i.e. the solution file points to a project file that's missing from the disk). Does anyone know how to enforce a failure under these conditions?

Comment: I don't see any command line switches to "validate" a solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx. Does a warning get spat out about the missing project? If so in theory you could put the devenv output to a file and then search the file for the project missing warning and fail the build if you find it. Searching the file would be easy using Nant.

Comment: Can you use msbuild to build your project? Msbuild will report errors like this.

Comment: Yes, possibly. I had considered that, but with something like 40 devenv projects under my wing I was concerned that it might be a big conversion job.